# Macホスト上の仮想ゲストLinuxへ別のWindowsホストからの接続が極端に遅い

Tags: windows, vmware, vmware-fusion

ホストOS：　MacOS 10.12
仮想化ソフトウェア：　VMWare Fusion７
ゲストOS:　Ubuntu12.04（仮にAとします）
接続しようとしている別のホストOS： Windows7（仮にBとします）

上記の環境において、A上に構築したWebサイトへBから接続しようとした場合、
接続が極端に遅く、数分待ってようやくページが開くような状態です。

なお、同じネットワーク上にある他のMacやiPhone7からは正常に接続できています。
しかし、同じネットワーク上にあるWindows7は2台ともに同じ症状です。

何かWindows側の設定が必要でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

よくある原因としては、WEBサーバがアクセス元のクライアントIPアドレスからホスト名を
DNSで検索しにいこうとして、検索タイムアウトまで時間がかかる、というものが考えられます。
Ubuntu環境の/etc/hostsにWindowsマシンのIPアドレスとホスト名を追記すると解消されませんか?

なお、tcpdumpやwiresharkが利用可能なら、通信をパケットキャプチャして
WEBアクセス時によけいな通信が発生していないか確認すると、原因特定しやすくなると思います。